# SwiftUI: How can I limit a string to be displayed as one line, and support automatic scaling to a specified ratio, sliding to view the full text

Tags: ios, swift, string, swiftui

How can I limit a string to be displayed as one line, and support automatic scaling to a specified ratio, and support sliding to view the full text without being truncated in SwiftUI

**problem**

(1).minimumScaleFactor(0.3)  // doesn't work

(2)text is being truncated // hope it won't be truncated

Here is the code

---

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State private var text = "In the scrollview of SwiftUI, I have a very long string, which is limited to one line, and automatically scaled to the specified ratio, and can slide to display the full content without being truncated"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 80))
                .lineLimit(1)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
        }
        Text("this is another text")
    }
}
```

}

---

[simulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrDbJ.jpg)

The string to be displayed as one line, and support automatic scaling to a specified ratio, and support sliding to view the full text without being truncated in SwiftUI.

Comment: (1).minimumScaleFactor(0.3) // doesn't work

(2)text is being truncated // hope it won't be truncated

Comment: I understand the first part, but why don't you want the text to be truncated? If the text is not truncated, what's the point of being able to scroll?

Comment: Because in fact, the number of characters in the text of this string will be sometimes long and sometimes short. I hope that when the number of characters is short, the font will be displayed larger, and when the number of characters is long, the font will be displayed smaller, and I only allow it to be displayed in one line of space, so I hope it can Swipe to see the full string

Comment: sorry, I'm new to the stackoverflow from china, I hope I've made the question clear, thanks. @Sweeper

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly...

- you would like the text to be displayed as large as possible in the space available
- as soon as there is too much text for the space available, the font size should begin to shrink so that it still fits into the space available if possible
- once it has reached minimum size, it should be possible to scroll the text in order to see the rest of the line, without it being truncated.

The problem you were having in your example is that the `ScrollView` disables the scaling.

What you can do is let SwiftUI fit the text into the space available as best as possible without a `ScrollView`, but then overlay this with a `ScrollView` to overcome the truncation (in case truncation is necessary). The overlay is constrained by the height of the base view, so the font is forced to shrink. The (truncated) base view is masked out by applying a background to the overlay.

Here you go *(EDIT: comments added to code)*:

```swift
    @State private var text = "In the scrollview of SwiftUI, I have a very long string, which is limited to one line, and automatically scaled to the specified ratio, and can slide to display the full content without being truncated"

    private func formattedText(key: String) -> some View {
        Text(LocalizedStringKey(key))
            .font(.system(size: 80))
            .lineLimit(1)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
    }

    private func textLine(_ key: String) -> some View {

        // Show the text as best as possible in the space
        // available. The text will be truncated if it is
        // very long and cannot be scaled any further
        formattedText(key: key)
            .overlay(

                // Show the text again, but this time inside a
                // ScrollView. This will overcome any truncation
                // that might have occurred before. The height
                // is constrained by the base view, so this will
                // force the font to shrink to the same size
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    formattedText(key: key)
                }
                // Mask out the base view
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            textLine(text)
            textLine("this is another text")
        }
    }
```

[image: text line]

Comment: Thank you so much, what you did is exactly what i want, you did a great job and really helped me a lot! @Benzy Neez

Comment: Hello, @Benzy Neez

The code works fine so far. But there is still a small problem. When I try to fix the frame height of the string to 90, the fontsize will not be automatically scaled. How should I solve it? thanks

here is the code:

        private func formattedText(key: String) -> some View {
            Text(LocalizedStringKey(key))
                .font(.system(size: 80))
                .frame(height: 90)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
        }

Comment: @kennylin Just remove the line ```.frame(height: 90)``` from the function ```formattedText``` and set it as the very last line of the function ```textLine``` instead.